# Convert 3D graph to region

Tags: graphs-and-networks, regions

I have a Graphics3D element and want to calculate its RegionCentroid. However, a graph is not considered a proper region by Mathematica. How can I convert my graph (which has tubes or cylinders as edges) into a region in order to be able to treat it like a 3-D object rather than a graph?

Answer (score 5):

One way is to convert to a 3D graphics, then to a region:

```
graph = ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, (x + y)^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
dgraph = DiscretizeGraphics[Show[graph]];
RegionCentroid[dgraph]

(* {1.9645*10^-6, -1.44681*10^-6, 1.05721} *)
```

This works on 2D and 3D graphs. You can then use region functions, e.g., RegionCentroid to get the centroid of the whole graph.